# Fail Build if NuGet version cannot be found

Tags: c#, nuget

Can I force the build to fail if NuGet cannot find a correct version.

I get this error and it should be failing the build, but it is not.

`Dependency specified was org.package >= 1.0.3-* but ended up with org.package 1.0.1-pre2.`

Comment: Depends on which build system you are talking about.

Comment: Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 - On prem. (although in any environment, my local vs2015, TFS build server, TeamCity...)  I believe this is being generated when doing a 'dnu restore'

Comment: When you say "TFS build server" are you talking about xaml builds or are you talking about the new TfsBuild system added in 2015?

Comment: XAML builds, but we are trying to migrate to the new TfsBuild system.